# Creating a helper or duplicating functions in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, software-design

I have a set of functions that are called from 2 different models [ and maybe more in the future ] 
What's the best approach to deal with this : 
1 - Duplicated in each model
2 - Creating a helper for those functions and loading that helper from each model 
Do you suggest any other approach

Comment: What kind of functions are they?  Can you show some code?  Helper would work, base model class could work, a new model could work, a static method in one of your model could work, a library could work, ...

Comment: 2 - Creating a helper for those functions and loading that helper from each model in order to reduce code redundancy if they are same.

Comment: @MaximeMorin Basically a notification functions and wrapping up . Something like sending SMS / Emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a base model that your individual models extend, giving them all a shared ancestor of sorts.

Create the file `application/core/MY_Model.php`

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    public function common_method($param)
    {
        // Stuff goes here
    }
}
```

Then, any model that you wish to use the common method(s) in should simply extend `MY_Model` instead of `CI_Model`.

Note that the `MY_` prefix is the default for CI, but you can change it in the `application/config/config.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Its my approach i don't know its a proper one or not.
If you are using this function throughout the site,  You can create the class with those functions and add it in a library.

If you like you can do autoload also if require. Based on your usage.

Comment: Thanks .. i'll look up when to create library and when to create helper . If you have something useful i'd appreciate that

Comment: @iyadalaqel I think the best example would be to check the [Email helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/email_helper.html) versus the [Email library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html).  In short, helpers are based on the procedural style while libraries are based on OOP. Feel free to check the sources for more details on those two.